# How to calculate odds ratio of continuous vs binary variable?

Tags: r, odds-ratio

I'm trying to understand the statistics done by someone who I can't reach. The study is about enuresis in small children.

The enuresis variable is binary (1 or 0, or the child usually wets the bed at the age of 5 or it doesn't). Some of the other variables are binary, like toilet training process (using or not a specific method) and presence/absence of constipation. To such binary variables, I calculated the odds ratio in R as follows.

```
fit = glm(enuresis~method,data=e,family=binomial)
summary(fit) # p = 0.0384
odds.ratio(fit) # OR = 2.25694, p = 0.03839
```

The numbers were exactly the same as the previous statistic analysis, which made me think they're right.

Problem comes when the independent variable is continuous, for instance the age (in months) in which diurnal diaper was removed.

```
fit = glm(enuresis~monthDiapRm,data=e,family=binomial)
summary(fit) # p = 0.0716
odds.ratio(fit) # OR = 1.02531, p = 0.07158
```

The previous analysis found OR = 1.790, p = 0.0179.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41384075/1086511) with the same variable types, and the GLM employed was the same. So, what's wrong here? Is there a better way to calculate the Odds Ratio and the p?

Comment: What happens when you include both variables in the model?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Like `glm(enuresis~monthDiapRm+method,data=e,family=binomial)`? OR = 1.034086 and 2.916356, p = 0.020671 and 0.009297. What for?

Comment: Typically, estimates can change when other variables are included in the model (as they have done here).  Wanted to check that a model which adjusts for both at the same time would not yield the original estimates.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Well, there are other variables too, but since most agree with the previous analysis, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Could age have been a factor in the original model? You don’t have to model age as continuous if the sample is large relative to the number of possible ages.

Comment: @dimitriy I have 32 distinct ages (in months), and 373 subjects. Still, it would be good to learn how to do it both ways (continuous and discrete).

Comment: Try as.factor(age) in your code.

Comment: @dimitriy Now it gives me a different OR (1 or very small) and p (about 1) for each age.